# Webcam for video call - eye level

Tags: video, skype, webcam

I've begun doing video calls with a Logitech webcam.  Problem is that mounting on top or bottom of monitor looks awful - can't make eye contact with the person, the angle is up or down my face.  How can I mount the camera so it's eye level?

One idea I had was to clip eye level to the *side* of the monitor.  But A) I can't rotate the image and B) it's hard to make it stay there.

Answer (score 2):

Get a small camera stand - such as [this example](http://www.amazon.co.uk/ShaniTech-Mini-Camera-Tripod-Silver/dp/B000WLFNCC), assuming your cam has the appropriate screw-thread.

However, you'll have to set the cam right in front of their face on screen to achieve what you ask - might be somewhat distracting.

Answer (score 0):

Dangle it from the ceiling on a string. Use more strings to stabalize it so it faces forward. Put it on a pulley to move it out of the way when not in use.

Answer (score 0):

Try a desktop teleprompter product like this:

[image: video grab]

https://www.bodelin.com/proprompter/proprompter-desktop

If its really that big of an issue for you.

Comment: Clever product if what you need is a teleprompter.  Looks like it would interfere with the screen for other applications.